# Merge multiple join records into one by id

Tags: sql

*Better title? Please edit.*

Having two tables:

```
# table1
       id   name  desc
  --------------------
        1   Nim   blah
        2   Rod   blah
        3   Nero  blah

# table2
id_table1  rank  url
----------------------
        1     1  U11
        1     2  U12
        1     3  U13
        2     1  U21
        3     1  U31
        3     2  U32
```

Currently I am using a JOIN query and typically get:

```
 id  name  desc   url
 ---------------------
  1  Nim   blah   U11
  1  Nim   blah   U12
  1  Nim   blah   U13
  2  Rod   blah   U21
  3  Nero  blah   U31
  3  Nero  blah   U32
```

I am wondering if there is a query that will deliver something like:

```
 id  name  desc   url(1)  url(2)  url(3)
 -------------------------------------
  1  Nim   blah   U11     U12     U13
  2  Rod   blah   U21     NULL    NULL
  3  Nero  blah   U31     U32     NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the number of potential columns, one option is to use `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` your results:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.desc, 
       max(case when t2.rank = 1 then t2.url end) url1,
       max(case when t2.rank = 2 then t2.url end) url2,
       max(case when t2.rank = 3 then t2.url end) url3
from table1 t1
       join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_table1
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.desc
```

Comment: Great! Yes, I know the number of potential columns as of current design. If it changes I can do a pre-query to determine this and generate the `max()` segment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the options in single columns? Otherwise `group_concat` could be interesting:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.desc,
   group_concat(DISTINCT t2.url) as urls
FROM table1 t1 
   INNER JOIN table2 t2 
           ON t.id = t2.id_table1;
```